# Azure Databricks Default DNS IPs?

Tags: azure, databricks

In my Azure Databricks workspace the default DNS IP is #168.63.129.16, this DNS doesn't resolve azure storage accounts which were created a year ago, after switching the 8.8.8.8 then the cluster sees these storage accounts.

Is there a command line that helps to get the list of default Azure Databricks DNS server IPs and is there is away to learn latest DNS refresh date !?

Comment: Databricks gets DNS from the Azure VNet settings - you may need to reach your networking team

Comment: @Alex Thanks Alex indeed, 168.63.129.16 seems a first class citizen in Azure Cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address **168.63.129.16** is a virtual public IP address that is used to facilitate a communication channel to Azure platform resources. Customers can define any address space for their private virtual network in Azure. Therefore, the Azure platform resources must be presented as a unique public IP address.
Click [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16)!